# Query doesn't return in Sqlite but works in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I am not sure why this query is not working in Sqlite. There is no MySql specific operators/commands. It works on mySql but returns 0 results in sqlite. They both have the same exact database.

```
SELECT s1.wordid, s1.synsetid, s1.sensekey, synsets.definition
   , s2.wordid AS matchedWordID, w.*
FROM senses AS s1
   LEFT JOIN synsets ON s1.synsetid = synsets.synsetid
   LEFT JOIN senses AS s2 ON s1.synsetid = s2.synsetid AND s1.wordid <> s2.wordid
   LEFT JOIN words AS w ON s2.wordid = w.wordid
WHERE s1.wordid = 79459
;
```

Comment: The evidence indicates that the databases are not identical. Create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5).

Comment: You are right. There was an issue with the database.